# How to access dual value of a constraint implied by dvar bounds?

Tags: java, linear-programming, cplex

Given a simple (nonsense) linear program:

```
Minimize
 obj: x1 + x2 + x3
Subject To
 CT1: x1 + x2 + x3 = 5
Bounds
 1 <= x1 <= 100
 0 <= x2 <= 100
 0 <= x3 <= 100
```

I use the Java Cplex Interface to get dual values of the constraint(s). Obviously, I can easily read the dual of CT1 by calling `cplex.getDual( ct1 );`.
My question is: How can I read the dual value of the "constraint" `1 <= x1`, which is implied by the bounds of the decision variable? Or do I just have to add this explicitly as a constraint?

Comment: That's right: add it as a constraint

Comment: Check how to get a variable's [reduced cost](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.html#getReducedCost(ilog.concert.IloNumVar)).